# LEFT JOIN with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I am having trouble joining 3 tables together. I have a `SELECT` that works for two of the tables, which is the main data i'd like to see. I would also like to add the rate and tax to the units that are selected. They are stored in a different table because units can have more than one rate in my situation. Here is the query that works:

```
SELECT u.unit_name from units u 
LEFT JOIN reservations r ON r.unit = u.id
    AND r.arrival <= 2013-10-11
    AND r.departure >= 2013-10-01
WHERE r.unit IS NULL
```

And the one I am trying to make that doesn't:

```
SELECT u.unit_name, ur.unit, ur.rate, ur.tax
FROM units u
LEFT JOIN reservations r 
INNER JOIN unit_rates ur 
    ON r.unit = u.id
    ON ur.unit = u.id
    AND r.arrival <= 2013-10-11
    AND r.departure >= 2013-10-01
WHERE r.unit IS NULL 
    AND ur.active = TRUE
```

HERE is the SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b303ad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.unit_name, ur.unit, ur.rate, ur.tax 
FROM units u 
LEFT JOIN reservations r ON r.unit = u.id
AND r.arrival <= 2013-10-11
AND r.departure >= 2013-10-01
JOIN unit_rates ur ON ur.unit = u.id
WHERE r.unit IS NULL
```

Put the ON condition after each JOIN.

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25715/5)

Comment: it's not yeilding any results. Should I not be using INNER for the second JOIN? A RIGHT JOIN works but leaves the names NULL...?

Comment: Depends on what you need show some sample data in the original post.

Comment: tried to make this sqlfiddle: `CREATE TABLE unit_rates
(
id int,
unit int(4),
rate decimal(10,4),
tax decimal(10,4),
active tinyint(1)
);

INSERT INTO unit_rates(id, unit, rate, tax, active)
VALUES (1, 1000, 100.00, 10.00, 1);

CREATE TABLE units
{
id int,
name varchar(10)
};
INSERT INTO units (id, name) VALUES (1000, "BOB");

CREATE TABLE reservations
{
id int, unit int(4), arrival varchar(10), departure varchar(10)
        };

INSERT INTO reservations (1, 1000, "2013-09-25", "2013-09-30");`
but it wouldn't build.

Comment: I placed it in there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AND` within your ON:

```
SELECT u.unit_name, ur.unit, ur.rate, ur.tax
FROM units u
LEFT JOIN reservations r
INNER JOIN unit_rates ur 
/* Another table */
ON r.unit = u.id
    AND ur.unit = u.id
    AND r.arrival <= 2013-10-11
    AND r.departure >= 2013-10-01
WHERE r.unit IS NULL AND ur.active = TRUE
```

Comment: I get this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE r.unit IS NULL AND ur.active = TRUE LIMIT 0, 30' at line 10`